# Laravel - Disable automatically escaped character "<" (Less-than sign)

Tags: php, laravel

I've found out that Laravel form requests automatically escape the "<" (Less-than sign), but only in the case when there is a character coming afterward (excluding whitespace).

Example successful input (Input is: foo < bar)

```
"comments" => "foo < bar"
```

Example failed input (Input is: foo < bar \r\n bar <foo)

```
"comments" => """
  foo < bar\r\n
  bar 
  """
```

It automatically trims the string, right after the following character of the less-than sign.
Dumping directly the `$_POST` variable shows all the data correctly, however, the data gets escaped and is not possible to be accessed within the request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this **"comments" => htmlspecialchars("foo < bar")**

Comment: It does not work like that. The request goes thru the FormRequest object, and after that, the validated data can be accessed . I've already tried a similar solution by adding htmlspecialchars and str_replace, in the prepareForValidation() hook.